Assign multiple values to multiple variables with unique requirements with one SQL Statement
I am working within DB2 and the IBM i.  I am attempting to pull strings out of log files in our IFS using the QSYS2.IFS_READ table function.  These log files have 5 pieces of data that I want and each day there are roughly 25 log files that generate.  So, I have a cursor that iterates through each log file and then runs 6 queries against each log file pulling the data that I want based off of the record COUNT minus the static position of each piece of data.
This is the quickest way I could think to do this, but it runs for 23 minutes, which isn't quick.
I am imagining a CASE statement may work well?
Either way, my SQL is below:
BEGIN

DECLARE @path_name VARCHAR(28);
DECLARE @job VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @run_date TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE @warnings VARCHAR(4);
DECLARE @errors VARCHAR(4);
DECLARE @job_complete VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @elapsed VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @rec_count INTEGER;

FOR @V1 AS @C1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PATH_NAME, CREATE_TIMESTAMP FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_OBJECT_STATISTICS(
        START_PATH_NAME => '/<PATH_NAME>',
        SUBTREE_DIRECTORIES => 'YES'))
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(PATH_NAME, '\d{8}.LOG')
    AND CREATE_TIMESTAMP >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 DAY
    ORDER BY PATH_NAME
DO
SET @rec_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ(
                PATH_NAME => @V1.PATH_NAME)));

SET @vault_job = (SELECT REPLACE((SUBSTR(LINE, 46, 10)), '/', '') FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ(
                    PATH_NAME => @V1.PATH_NAME))
                    WHERE LINE_NUMBER = 5);

SET @errors = (SELECT SUBSTR(LINE, 78, 4) FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ(
                PATH_NAME => @V1.PATH_NAME))
                WHERE LINE_NUMBER = (@rec_count - 18));

SET @warnings = (SELECT SUBSTR(LINE, 78, 4) FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ(
                PATH_NAME => @V1.PATH_NAME))
                WHERE LINE_NUMBER = (@rec_count - 17));

SET @job_complete = (SELECT SUBSTR(LINE, 53, 20) FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ(
                    PATH_NAME => @V1.PATH_NAME))
                    WHERE LINE_NUMBER = (@rec_count - 2));

SET @elapsed = (SELECT SUBSTR(LINE, 49, 8) FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ(
                PATH_NAME => @V1.PATH_NAME))
                WHERE LINE_NUMBER = (@rec_count - 1));                

CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('----------------------------');
CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('Job: ' || @job);
CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('Path name: ' || @V1.PATH_NAME);
CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('Create Time: ' || @V1.CREATE_TIMESTAMP);
CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('errors: ' || @errors);
CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('warnings: ' || @warnings);
CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('job complete at ' || @job_complete);
CALL SYSTOOLS.LPRINTF('elapsed: ' || @elapsed);
END FOR;

END



It's been a while since I flexed my DB2 muscles, but see if this does anything for you: https://pastebin.com/aSAhnGUQ
